# Telegram скорость передачи данных по Inline кнопкам

Tags: api, telegram, бот, inline

Необходимо дать клиенту вводить пинкод в телеграмме. Проблема в том, что вебхук теряет символы, либо присылает не в том порядке, если например их перетыкать за секунду. Как с этим можно справиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таких случаях update_id последовательно увеличивается. При вводе PIN-кода накапливайте полученные данные, сортируя входящие обновления по возрастанию идентификаторов. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update

Comment: getUpdates не работает, если включен Webhook. Или вы предлагаете выключать вебхук на время ввода пинкода и включать после?

Comment: На URL, установленный для webhook'а, сервер уже присылает объект Update со всеми нужными полями. Способ получения обновлений тут никакой роли не играет.